# CSipSimple can't hear when calling from Jitsi or vice-versa when openvpn connected on one of the devices

Tags: android, windows, sip, openvpn, jitsi

First of all my English is not good, but i will try my best to explain the problem I face.

I configured Ostel (SIP) on PC (Jitsi) and on Android phone (CSipSimple) according instructions on Ostel website, registration successful, everything is OK with that.

The problem begins when I try to call from pc to phone or vice-versa.

On PC I have OpenVPN connected, on phone I don't have any VPN. When I call from PC to phone with OpenVPN connected, we cannot hear each other, connection established, although no ZRTP handshake is established (there is not 4 digits code appear). But when I disconnect the OpenVPN on my PC and then make a call, everything is ok, we can hear each other and 4 digits appear, ZRTP is established. When I connect OpenVPN on both devices (on PC and on phone) we again can hear each other and ZRTP is established.

What I want is to use Ostel between VPN-connected PC and without VPN-connected phone or PC or whatever device is.

What I need to do to fix this problem?

thank you beforehand

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Jitsi and CSipSimple send their INTERNET IP-address instead of sending their VPN IP-address in SDP during INVITE request
Altghough CSipSimple has the parameter "Allow SDP NAT rewrite" in Expert mode of account setup. And it should be ticked to avoid this problem. 
But Jitsi does not have such option